Context Language Not Getting Resolved on Filter in Mutilingual Site
I Have multilingual Site with 3 languages, while getting context language in OnActionExecute in Action Filter, Context Language always coming as same irrespective of current page language.
How to resolve this.

Are you using any custom action filter? If yes can you add in your question how you are trying to get this?

Is it a page call or an API call using custom route? If it's API call, maybe adding sc_lang parameter to the API call would help?

@SumitBhatia
public class SessionValidate: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
                        var language = Context.Language.ToString();

}

@MarekMusielak It's page call only, on action filter neither context item nor context language correct value I am getting.

@vikas Are you binding this attribute directly to the sitecore controller inside action method..Can you please confirm...

@ckhanna yes directly under controller

@vikas Can we connect over sitecore slack..Need to check the caching on your rendering?
